# Is there a way to extract IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts to a cheat sheet?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I often open the *IntelliJ keyboard* settings to see what the different keyboard shortcuts are, but it would be pretty useful to have that in a printed form. Lookup by `⇧⌘A` helps in learning too, but I'd like to have an overview of some selected keyboard shortcuts always at hand.

Is there any way to get a cheat sheet from IntelliJ keyboard settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is **Keymap Exporter** plugin that "allows to export IntelliJ IDEA keymaps at the PDF format". Once installed available under `Tools` menu.
2. Try **Key promoter** plugin -- every time you use an action using a mouse and if that action has keyboard shortcut, this plugin will show you small tooltip/popup/reminder about it.

Comment: That's what I wanted. The Promoter works, it's useful for learning. Keymap Exporter does not show up in the Tool menu. When I create a key shortcut to execute it I get an error in the console. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Possibly it's no longer compatible with current builds then -- no other explanation. See if you can contact the author: https://github.com/denis-zhdanov/intellij-plugin-export-keymap/issues  **P.S.** AFAIK author works for JetBrains (or at least worked in the past)

Comment: Thanks I try to contact him

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do it from inside IntelliJ IDEA, but you could just print [the ref card from JetBrains' website](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).